# Text positioning in multi-column tables

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a word document containing tables. The columns have different column width. Attached here.
[image]

I want to translate the word table into LaTex. The new table in LaTeX looks quite bad. The alignment of text are bad. In addition, I am getting warning from Overleaf as 'Overfull' \hbox. I'm not sure why am I getting warning regarding the width of the table. 
The new table is here.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[margin=24mm,
        bottom= 5mm,%
        footskip=4\baselineskip,
        includefoot,
        % showframe
        ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, scopes}
\tikzset{FOOT/.style = {
every node/.append style = {font=\sffamily\bfseries,
                        text=white,
                        align=center,
                        minimum height=15mm,
                        outer sep=0pt,
                        },
           sx/.style = {xshift=##1mm}
                    }
    }
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
% To add URL of website
\usepackage{url}
% Set line spacing using the following package
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\definecolor{darkgoldenrod}{rgb}{0.72, 0.53, 0.04}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
% \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO]{Development Action Plan}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields

%%========================= Footer template ============================
\fancyfoot[O]{% odd pages
\begin{tikzpicture}[FOOT,
remember picture, overlay,
node distance=0pt]
\node (O1) [minimum width=25mm,
        above right=of current page.south west]
        {};
\node (O2) [minimum width=0.5\textwidth, align=left,
        right=of O1]
        { Continuing Professional Development\\
            \footnotesize
          January 2019};
\node (O3) [minimum width=0.5\textwidth,
        align=center,
        right=of O2]
        { LarCoS\\
            \footnotesize
        Membership no. 123456\qquad};
\node (O4) [minimum width=25mm, font=\sffamily\bfseries,
        right=of O3]
        {\thepage~of~\pageref*{LastPage}};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[teal] (O1.south west) |- ([sx= 3] O3.north east)
                        -- ([sx=-3] O3.south east)
                         -- cycle;
\fill[black] ([sx=-3] O2.south east) -- ([sx= 3] O2.north east) -|
        (O4.south east) -- cycle;
\path[white, line width=1mm, shorten >=-0.5mm, shorten < =-0.5mm]
        ([sx=-3] O2.south east) edge ([sx=3] O2.north east)
        ([sx=-3] O4.south west) edge ([sx=3] O4.north west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
            } %odd page
%%%%==========================================
%%========================= Footer template ============================
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
\begin{tabular}{|C{0.75cm}|C{0.7cm}|L{3cm}|L{3.25cm}|L{3cm}|L{2.7cm}|L{3cm}|L{2.45cm}|L{2.1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{|l|}{\textbf{Job role and responsibilities:}}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Review of learning needs}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Development plan}}\\ \hline
\textbf{Date} & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}In what area do \\  I need to improve \\ my  performance?\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}How does this link\\ to other objectives\\  (eg employer, ICE,\\  etc)?\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}What do I need\\  to learn in\\  order to \\ achieve this?\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}What will I do\\  to achieve this?\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}What are the \\ likely resources \\ and support \\ that I will need?\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}How will I\\ evaluate a\\ successful \\ outcome?\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}What are\\ my \\ deadlines \\for meeting \\this target?\end{tabular}} \\ \hline

Jul 2006 &   RB-DAP-01   &~Understanding structural steel detail drawings and preparing design drawing using AutoCAD~&~Knowledge of load transfer thorough proper detailing and to be represented in drawings  &  Several structural components and their behaviour under loading; for AutoCAD, needed to learn the commands  &  Rigorous study of design drawings and draw the details using AutoCAD  &  Drawings from previous projects and the software AutoCAD and its manuals & I shall be able to prepare structural detailing using AutoCAD & Sep 2006 \\ \hline



              &              &                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                             &                                                                                     &                                                                                                                       &                                                                                                      &                                                                                                          \\ \hline



              &              &                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                             &                                                                                     &                                                                                                                       &                                                                                                      &                                                                                                          \\ \hline



              &              &                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                             &                                                                                     &                                                                                                                       &                                                                                                      &                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Your table cannot be compiled as is. What are the `C` and `L` column specifiers?

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences. Uploaded the correct one.

Comment: in your columns definitions replace `m{...}` with `p{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text area)

i reduce your mwe to the part concerning only table. for it i add three packages: `ragged2e` (for nicer hyphenation of text in table's cells) `makecell` (for more vertical space around cells' contents) and `tabularx` (for multi line cells with equal width):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=24mm,
        bottom= 5mm,%
        footskip=4\baselineskip,
        includefoot,
        % showframe
        ]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % <---

\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabularx}  % <---

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering  \arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|*{7}{L|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{|l|}{\textbf{Job role and responsibilities:}}   \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Review of learning needs}}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Development plan}}            \\
    \hline
\textbf{Date}
    & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{In what area do  I need to improve my  performance?}
        & \textbf{How does this link to other objectives  (eg employer, ICE,  etc)?}
            & \textbf{What do I need to learn in order to achieve this?}
                & \textbf{What will I do to achieve this?}
                    & \textbf{What are the likely resources and support that I will need?}
                        & \textbf{How will I evaluate a successful  outcome?}
                            & \textbf{What are my deadlines for meeting this target?}   \\
    \hline
Jul 2006 & \makecell[tl]{RB-\\DAP-\\01}
    & Understanding structural steel detail drawings and preparing design drawing using AutoCAD
        & Knowledge of load transfer thorough proper detailing and to be represented in drawings
            &  Several structural components and their behaviour under loading; for AutoCAD, needed to learn the commands
                &  Rigorous study of design drawings and draw the details using AutoCAD
                    &  Drawings from previous projects and the software AutoCAD and its manuals
                        & I shall be able to prepare structural detailing using AutoCAD
                            & Sep 2006                      \\
    \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\                                                                                                 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

**remarks:**

- for better fitting texts in cells you should consider to use smaller font size. for example `\small` or even `footnotesize`
- for column head try to use shorter name. for example, for the lat solumn instead of *Deadline for meeting this target?* rather us simply *Deadlines* (in for column type of this column use `c` or `l`)

**addendum:**
from your comment below can be understand, that your table will spam many (at least two) pages. in this case you need:

- remove float environment `table` for using `tabularx` you should replace it (or just add) the package `ltablex`, which combine properties of the `longtable` and `tabularx` packages
- for preserving standard `tabularx` features (which is slightly changed with the `ltablex` package
- define the first and other table headers (if you like to repeat them on the each page), table foots and the last table foot (see mwe below)

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[margin=24mm,
              bottom= 5mm,%
              footskip=4\baselineskip,
              includefoot,
              % showframe
              ]{geometry}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}

  \usepackage{array, ltablex, makecell, multirow}
  \keepXColumns
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\theadgape{}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering  \arraybackslash}X}

  \begin{document}

      \begingroup
      \setcellgapes{5pt}
      \makegapedcells
      \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
      \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|*{6}{L|}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6em}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{9}{|l|}{\textbf{Job role and responsibilities:}}   \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Review of learning needs}}
      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Development plan}}            \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Date}
      & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{In what area do  I need to improve my  performance?}
          & \textbf{How does this link to other objectives  (eg employer, ICE,  etc)?}
              & \textbf{What do I need to learn in order to achieve this?}
                  & \textbf{What will I do to achieve this?}
                      & \textbf{What are the likely resources and support that I will need?}
                          & \textbf{How will I evaluate a successful  outcome?}
                              & \textbf{Deadline for meeting this target?}   \\
      \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{9}{|l|}{\textbf{Job role and responsibilities (cont.):}}   \\
      \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Review of learning needs}}
      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Development plan}}            \\
      \hline
  \textbf{Date}
      & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{In what area do  I need to improve my  performance?}
          & \textbf{How does this link to other objectives  (eg employer, ICE,  etc)?}
              & \textbf{What do I need to learn in order to achieve this?}
                  & \textbf{What will I do to achieve this?}
                      & \textbf{What are the likely resources and support that I will need?}
                          & \textbf{How will I evaluate a successful  outcome?}
                              & \textbf{Deadlines for meeting this target?}   \\
      \hline
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{9}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page:}}   \\
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
  Jul 2006 & \makecell[tl]{RB-\\DAP-\\01}
      & Understanding structural steel detail drawings and preparing design drawing using AutoCAD
          & Knowledge of load transfer thorough proper detailing and to be represented in drawings
              &  Several structural components and their behaviour under loading; for AutoCAD, needed to learn the commands
                  &  Rigorous study of design drawings and draw the details using AutoCAD
                      &  Drawings from previous projects and the software AutoCAD and its manuals
                          & I shall be able to prepare structural detailing using AutoCAD
                              & Sep 2006  \\
      \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\  \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &           \\
      \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \endgroup

  \end{document}
  ```

**note:**
`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is used for limiting some settings  (font size,  additional vertical space) of table only to this table

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zarko!! But I want to use it as 'longtable'. When I try to use the 'longtable' I'm getting error message. 
What should I change? The 'tabularx' ?

Comment: @LaCos, where is this mentioned in your question? how should i know this? please edit your question and clarify what you like to have (table over many pages).

Comment: @LarCos, see edited answer.